# Different behavior in JAR file vs Runnable JAR file exported from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm getting different results from the code below depending upon whether I select **JAR file** or **Runnable JAR file** from Eclipse's File|Export dialog:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Enumeration<URL> dirs = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources(
                "com/test/pojo");
    System.out.println(dirs.hasMoreElements());
}
```

If I choose:

- *JAR file* - the code above prints **false**
- *Runnable JAR file* - the code above prints **true**

I compared the contents of JARs exported both ways, and the files in them are exactly the same!

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Formatting, re-wording of the subject

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include actual enumeration values that you're getting in each case, instead of just showing that you got more than one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!ClassLoader.getResources() will load the classes in my jar, but none-runnable jar didn't maintain the correct directory enties.

Runnable-JAR:

```
jar tf hall1.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  com/
  com/test/
  com/test/Main.class
  com/test/pojo/
  com/test/pojo/Pojo.class
```

None-Runnable JAR:

```
jar tf hall1.jar
  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  com/test/Main.class
  com/test/pojo/Pojo.class
```

So all I have to do is selecting "Options-Add directory entries" in JAR-Export pannel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of my answer, but I'll try : your files are maybe the same, but it's doesn't imply that the meta-data of the files are the same, i.e. you can have to different files (e.g. in different format) but containing the same data. So maybe the meta-data of Runnable JAR and JAR are different (and it wouldn't be surprising).

Comment: I found the bytes length of two jars and different(the Runnable JAR is a bit larger than the other), although the files in them including meta files are all the same.So there must be some additional set-ups in Runnable JAR, which makes CLASS-LOADER preload class files. The question is what can I do to make Non-Runnable JAR to achieve the same goal?